# Excuting Java processes on a remote Windows machine when Developing on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, java, intellij-idea

My main development environment is in Linux. However, my execution environment for my application is on Windows. The language of choice is Java.

Is there anyway to setup IntelliJ to invoke the java process on the Windows remote machine? The application has items within it that can only be invoked on Windows. [Windows handles]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to install cygwin or another sshd on the Windows box, then script a combination of rsync and ssh to copy the class files and exec the remote Java application. There's some slight overhead, ~1 second, for using SSH, but I assume performance is not particularly a concern.  One of the great things about SSH is that the output streams back to the local box, so you can interpret the output or write additional regression tests against it.

Comment: I agree with this - but if you want to eliminate some overhead, start your ssh client with the `arcfour` cipher. With the command-line `ssh`, it's `ssh -c arcfour`, with PuTTY just set `arcfour` at the top of the ciphers list. Really speeds things up. Also in some cases, compression can help. `ssh -C` or the compression checkbox in PuTTY.